# How do I minimize list of charts with scrypt for mql5?

Tags: arrays, charts, mql, mql5, metatrader5

There is few charts opened in terminal, for example: AUDCAD, DKKSEK, AUDJPY, EURZAR, USDCZK, USDCHF.

And there is array of target charts: DKKSEK, EURZAR, USDCHF.

How do I minimize all charts windows except chart windows of target charts?

Answer (score 1):

```
void loopOverCharts()//loop over all the charts
  {
   long currChart,prevChart=ChartFirst(); 
   int i=0,limit=100; 
   processChart(prevChart);
   while(i<limit)
     { 
      currChart=ChartNext(prevChart);
      if(currChart<0) break;
      processChart(currChart);
      prevChart=currChart;
      i++;
     }
  }
void processChart(const long chartId)// process each chart
  {
   const string arrayOfSymbols[]={DKKSEK, EURZAR, USDCHF);
   //going over array of symbols to figure out whether need to minimize of not
   bool symbolToMinimize=true;
   for(int i=ArraySize(arrayOfSymbols)-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
      if(ChartSymbol(chartId)==arrayOfSymbols[i])
        {
         symbolToMinimize=false;
         break;
        }
     }
   //if do not have chart symbol in the list - minimize it
   if(symbolToMinimize)
       ChartSetInteger(chartId,CHART_IS_MINIMIZED,true);
  }
```

Comment: `ChartSetInteger(chartId,CHART_IS_MINIMIZED,true);` doesn't do anything with the latest builds and neither does `winapi`. :(

Comment: that is pity. it wont work in such case until MQ fix it

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing charts no longer works in MQL5. Your best bet is to iterate the charts and close the ones you don't need while bring the charts you do need to the top. Here is an example.

```
#define forEachInArray(TYPE, VAR, ARRAY) TYPE VAR;int SIZE##VAR=ArraySize(ARRAY);\
   for(int I##VAR=0;(I##VAR<SIZE##VAR)&&(((VAR=ARRAY[I##VAR])==NULL)||true);I##VAR++)
#define forEachChartId(VAR) \
   for(long VAR=ChartFirst();VAR>=0;VAR=ChartNext(VAR))


#include <charts/chart.mqh>
void OnStart()
{
   string targets[] = {"EURUSD", "GBPJPY", "EURCAD"};
   forEachChartId(id) {
      if(id == ChartID())
         continue;
      chart_manage(id, targets);
   }
   chart_manage(ChartID(), targets);
}

void chart_manage(long id, string &targets[])
{
   CChart chart;
   chart.Attach(id);
   forEachInArray(string, target, targets) {
      if(chart.Symbol() == target) {
         chart.BringToTop();
         chart.Detach();
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Remember to always close the chart that the script is running on **last**!